# Read nested nodes in XML using Jquery

Tags: jquery, xml

My XML Feed is at  http://tinyurl.com/6wc6fel

I am using following code to read the XML

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

          $.get("read.xml", function (data) {            
            alert('Load was performed.');
        });

    });

 </script>
```

Since its nested, I want to display folllwing information of the < Hotel > Tag

**a) StayDateRange(Start, End)

b) In  tag read HotelName,Location

c) Address1, Address2

d) In  tag read Url

e) In  tag read HotelFrontImage Url

f) In  tag NumberOfRooms>>Description**

and so on.. how do i do it ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use standard jQuery methods to traverse the xml. for example:

```
    $.get("read.xml", function (data) {   
        //this gets the attribute start from the tag StayDateRange
        $(data).find('Hotel').find('StayDateRange').attr('Start');
    });
```

Comment: i would suggest parsing xml with `parseXML` http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

Comment: @3nigma jquery should gess the fact that it's an xml and do that for you, after all $.get is a wrapper around $.ajax

Comment: @3nigma by default if you don't specify a datatype it defaults to intelligent guess http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Comment: @NicolaPeluchetti I tried to use your code at http://tinyurl.com/7sfedsy but its not showing anything can you help with jsfiddle

Comment: the attribute is `Start` **not** `start` try `$(data).find('hotel').find('StayDateRange').attr('Start');` that cant be replicated on jsfiddle because cross domain requests are not allowed

Comment: @user580950 for you it will not be cross domain but from a jsfiddle it would be

Comment: @3nigma  i tried your coede but its not displaying anything here http://tinyurl.com/7sfedsy

Comment: @user580950 that is because you are not appending it any where try `$('body').html($(data).find('hotel').find('StayDateRange').attr('Start'));`

Comment: @3nigma i did now but nothing shall i add a div something ?

Comment: @user580950 sry pal didn't really get the grasp of your problem

Comment: @3nigma I want to read that XML feed and display list of Hotels for example HotelName,Location

Comment: @user580950 i set - up a test fiddle to show you that  the xml traversing works http://jsfiddle.net/XEjzG/

Comment: @NicolaPeluchetti i used your code here http://tinyurl.com/7sfedsy but its not giving me any alert ?

Comment: @user580950 change `xml` with `data`

Comment: @NicolaPeluchetti great that works so in the XML if i want to Find all HotelName and show it in HTML how do i ?